# How can I resolve a red (moved) file in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

In Xcode 4 when you would move a file, you could resolve the new location of the file by clicking a button in the right menu, and selecting the new location through Finder.

In Xcode 5, there is no button in the right menu and I haven't found any way to specify the new location of the file through right clicking the file, or the top menu bar options.

Comment: I'm getting the same kind of issue with Xcode 6.3, for *all* files when I drag them into the project. I have to then use the File Inspector to tell Xcode where the file is to have it not show up in red. I did some reorganizing of files in the Xcode project. I wonder if this messed things up. My project does build, however.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

1. Right click the file in Xcode and select "Show File Inspector"
2. In the file inspector click the little folder icon next to the file path.

[image]

This will open a file dialog allowing you to update the file path.

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part. I didn't realize the tabs in the Utility menu were collapsible.

Comment: XCode 6.3 still has this problem. Deleting and re-adding files does not update the paths visible in the Inspector (although the project will compile successfully). Updating the path by clicking the folder icon works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the old one and add the moved one.