# Conversion to Swift 3 Files in Project Navigator changed to red and not accessible

Tags: swift3, ios10, xcode8

I'm in the process of converting an iOS project from Swift 2 to Swift 3. I've used Edit>Convert>to current Swift syntax... to convert the project. Everything compiles and runs okay.

A couple of files in the test target show up coloured red in the project navigator. Clicking on them does nothing. The files are there on the disk. Deleting from the project navigator and re adding doesn't help - file appears colored red again. This is affecting 2 out of about 40 files.

If I open one of the files in a separate text editor and introduce a syntax error and try to compile, xcode shows the error and I can open the file in xcode by clicking on the error. However in the project navigator the file still shows red and I can't open the file by clicking on it. So it looks like xcode is compiling it and running the tests - just can't see it in project navigator.

I've also tried closing xcode and a full machine reboot.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [How can I resolve a red (moved) file in Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603332/how-can-i-resolve-a-red-moved-file-in-xcode-5)

Open the file inspector, The location of the file has been lost and you need to tell xcode where to find it again.